# web scraping not showing any output

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

i'm new to web scraping and was trying to get a basic webscraping code to work. The code works just fine, the problem is that I cannot get the CSV file to have any information on it it only shows the name of each column that's it with no data. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

def scrape_cars(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
    cars = []
    for car_div in soup.find_all("div", class_="c-search-card"):
        car = {}
        car["title"] = car_div.find("h2").text.strip()
        car["price"] = car_div.find("div", class_="c-search-card__price").text.strip()
        car["location"] = car_div.find("div", class_="c-search-card__location").text.strip()
        car["year"] = car_div.find("div", class_="c-search-card__year").text.strip()
        car["km"] = car_div.find("div", class_="c-search-card__km").text.strip()
        car["color"] = car_div.find("div", class_="c-search-card__color").text.strip()
        car["carrosserie"] = car_div.find("div", class_="c-search-card__body-type").text.strip()
        car["puissance fiscale"] = car_div.find("div", class_="c-search-card__tax-horsepower").text.strip()
        car["boite"] = car_div.find("div", class_="c-search-card__transmission").text.strip()
        cars.append(car)
    return cars

url = "https://www.automobile.tn/fr/occasion"
cars = scrape_cars(url)

# write to CSV file
with open("cars.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=["title", "price", "location", "year", "km", "color", "carrosserie", "puissance fiscale", "boite"])
    writer.writeheader()
    for car in cars:
        writer.writerow(car)
```

this is what i get [the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stajE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of getting that information you're after:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm ## if using jupyter notebook: from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

big_list = []
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
for x in tqdm(range(1, 25)): ## to get all cars set range to 266
    soup = bs(s.get(f'https://www.automobile.tn/fr/occasion/{x}').text, 'html.parser')
    cars = soup.select('div[class="occasion-item"]')
    for c in cars:
        title = c.select_one('h2').text.strip()
        price = c.select_one('div[class="price"]').text.strip()
        big_list.append((title, price))
        ## add other elements as needed

df = pd.DataFrame(big_list, columns=['title', 'price'])
# df.to_csv('various_cars.csv') ## uncomment to save as csv
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
100%
24/24 [00:25<00:00, 1.08it/s]
title   price
0   Mazda CX-5  69 700 DT
1   Mercedes-Benz Classe E  53 000 DT
2   Mercedes-Benz Classe E  252 000 DT
3   Seat Arona  71 500 DT
4   Volkswagen Golf 7   47 000 DT
... ... ...
283 BMW Série 1 74 000 DT
284 BMW Série 3 135 000 DT
285 Volkswagen Golf 7   70 000 DT
286 Mercedes-Benz Classe C coupé    159 000 DT
287 Volkswagen Jetta    36 000 DT
288 rows × 2 columns
```